# KnpLabs DoctrineBehaviors translatable query count

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

I am using **KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors** translatable.
I have a **Post** entity and a **BlogCategory** entity.

**Post.php**

```
class Post
{
    use Timestampable;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="BlogCategory")
     * @JoinTable(name="post_categories")
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $categories;

    ...
}




class BlogCategory
{
    use Translatable;

    /**
     * @Id()
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

     ...
}




class BlogCategoryTranslation
{
    use Translation;

    /**
     * @Column()
     * @NotBlank()
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    ...
}
```

I want to show posts with related categories. But now I have a lot of queries.

How can I join translation in *many-to-many* association to optimize query count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a LEFT JOIN on the translations:

```
SELECT post, category, category_trans
FROM Post post
LEFT JOIN post.categories category
LEFT JOIN category.translations category_trans
```

If you want to only select the translation for the current language:

```
LEFT JOIN category.translations category_trans WITH category_trans.locale = :locale
```

(bind a `locale` parameter to the query).

If you're using query builder:

```
->leftJoin('category.translations', 'category_trans', 'WITH', category_trans.locale = :locale)
```